# How can I hide div on click outside using angularjs without writing directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to hide a div content on click of outside( body or document ). I don't want to write any directive for this.

I have written already, but button click and body click is merging one on one. SO if I click button , it is taking body click.

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown" ng-hide="filterClick">
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
                                <div class="filter-class"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

```js
$scope.showDropdown = function () {
      $scope.filterClick = !$scope.filterClick;
       if ($scope.filterClick) {
        angular.element(document).on('click', function () {
            console.log("close");
    });
    } else if(!$scope.filterClick){
        $scope.filterClick = false;
        window.onload = null;
         //--> trigger digest cycle and make angular aware. 
    }
    }
```

Here I want to hide the "dropdown-menu" div on click of outside. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Not much of an Angular fan but I saw "trigger digest cycle" and it makes me think of `$scope.$apply(...)` Take a look: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 0):

**Directive**

```
angular.element(document).on('click', function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.filterClick = true;
    })
});

$scope.showDropdown = function (e) {
    $scope.filterClick = !$scope.filterClick;
    e.stopPropagation(); //This will prevent from bubbling event to document
}
```